# Is there a way to make discord.py bots interact with/click other discord.py bot's message buttons?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

First time asker on stackoverflow, and I'll try my best to describe my situation for a nudge in the right direction!

I am attempting to use `discord.py` (specifically the `commands` from `discord.ext`, and `View` and `Button` from `discord.ui`) to create two different bots: one that creates a message with a set of buttons with various uses (including toggling off once, increasing forever, or decreasing to zero and then toggling off for now), and one bot that will randomly click one/some of these buttons so that users in the channel can simply watch the labels on the buttons change as if being clicked by other users.

This is partially for my own fun, as I've never worked a lot with python or the discord API and wanted to start with something somewhat easy (I'm a student at a school that uses way too much c++ and want to break out), and partially for a proof of concept because I have not seen any bots that interact with other bots in this way, yet it seems like an easy interaction from the outside.

Currently, bot 1 (the button-making bot) has the following important functions/classes:

```
# Define a view class that gives three buttons
class addThreeButtons(discord.ui.View):

    # Button 1 turns off and red when clicked. Starts as on and is colored green.
    @discord.ui.button(label='On', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="b1")
    async def turnOff(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # Change style and disable button
        if button.label == "On":
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.red
            button.disabled = True
            button.label = "Off"

        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self) # Update changes

    # Button 2 increments when clicked. Starts at 0, increases until button stops working.
    @discord.ui.button(label='0', style=discord.ButtonStyle.grey, custom_id="b2")
    async def inc(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # Start with current button val or set to erroneous 0 val
        value = int(button.label) if button.label else 0
        button.label = str(value + 1) # Increment label value
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self) # Update changes

    # Button 3 decrements from 10 when clicked until it reaches 0, and then disables.
    @discord.ui.button(label='10', style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id="b3")
    async def dec(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        # Start with current button val or erroneous 0 val
        value = int(button.label) if button.label else 0

        # Change style + disable button when 0 or below
        if value - 1 <= 0:
            button.style = discord.ButtonStyle.red
            button.disabled = True

        button.label = str(value - 1) # Decrement label value
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self) # Update changes

# Upon receiving buttons command, show message with three buttons
@bot.command()
async def buttons(ctx: commands.Context):
    await ctx.send("Here are your buttons!", view=addThreeButtons())
```

And this, on prompt, produces a correct message which reads "Here are your buttons!" with a single bar containing three buttons below that do exactly what is specified in the code.

Bot 2 (the button-clicking bot) is sadly a bit more stuck, and has the following important function thus far:

```
# On command run, search recent history for button-holding message, find buttons, and click them
@bot.command()
async def find_and_click_button(ctx):
    global currView # Create variable to hold view of key message
    childNum = 0 # Initialize number of buttons found on key message

    # Find the message with the intended buttons.
    async for message in ctx.history(limit=10):
        if message.content.startswith("Here are your buttons!"): # If found:

            await ctx.send("Found key message.") # Put status message in channel (extra)
            currView = View.from_message(message) # Switch active view to found message
            await ctx.send("View updated") # Put status message in channel (extra)

            for item in currView.children: # Iterate through "children" components (the buttons)
                childNum = childNum + 1 # Count them
            await ctx.send(f"Num kids: {childNum}") # Output the number of buttons found
            
            # Problem Line - Meant to click any/all buttons
            await ctx.send('interaction', check=lambda interaction: interaction.data["component_type"] == 2 and "custom_id" in interaction.data.keys())
```

This, on prompt, correctly searches the recent history for bot 1's message and correctly outputs that there are three children/buttons on the view of the message.  After trying a few versions of the final line, however, I cannot seem to find a direct way to *cause* an interaction on one of the buttons.

The current version using send is a derivative of this line: `response = await bot.wait_for('interaction', check=lambda interaction: interaction.data["component_type"] == 2 and "custom_id" in interaction.data.keys())` which I previously used successfully to *acknowledge* button interactions, but obviously have not adapted correctly to cause one.  I have also attempted to use a similar version of the problem line using `ctx.invoke` and was unable to figure out what syntax to use to invoke a button interaction as a WebHook event. I've also attempted to use `interaction.response` and `interaction.followup` to send the button presses, but again could not figure out the syntax needed for the bot to actually click a button.

Because I have not seen this specific application mentioned anywhere online so far in my searches, I am unsure by myself if the task I'm trying to accomplish is an intended feature of the API or not. My unfamiliarity with python and the discord API pushed me to reach out to a community with a bit better of a background, so here's my attempt!  I appreciate any recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Discord apps can [only receive](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands) (*not* send) interactions. It's not possible for a bot to click buttons or send slash commands, and there's not really an equivalent method to doing what you want for your bots to do. (*Technically*, you could use a user bot, but that's against the Discord TOS and there's not an API for it, so don't do it.)

Comment: Thank you! I figured this was likely the case, and so instead of reinventing the illegal-to-TOS wheel, I thought I'd ask.